# How can I remove mind control from my soldier?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

My one soldier who carries an arc caster just got mind controlled by the enemy. I would really like to capture this enemy rather than kill it, as I suspect I could learn a lot from it. How can I make it stop mind controlling my soldier without killing it?

Comment: Oops, too late. Oh, well, still curious for future reference

Comment: Tazer it? That's the only way I have to capture enemies right now.

Comment: did you read the question?  his only tazer dude has been mind controlled so he's trying to figure out how to remove it.

Comment: I think a psi can do it but I just got my first so I don't know. Other than that, kill the enemy I guess.

Comment: I think Mind Control has a duration of 5 turns in multiplayer - maybe same deal in single player?

Comment: Kill or stun the entity that's doing the controlling. Either way the control is disrupted.

Comment: @Shadur As I said in my question, and as spartacus pointed out, my only soldier with a tazer has been controlled, and I want to capture the enemy, so your solution is not an option.

Comment: In that case, your best bet is @Firmy's suggestion -- use disabling shot on the soldier to prevent him from shooting up the others, then play hide and seek for a few turns and hope your dude survives.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Mind Control wears off after 4 turns, what I did was run all my units way back out of LOS then every turn tab through my guys until the mind controlled unit was back under my command.

This is the only way if you don't want to kill the enemy. There is no way to break mind control other than kill the controller. Panicing him does not free the victim, and you can not mind control neither the controller nor the controlled guy during the duration of the link.

Comment: Your own mind control wears off after 3 turns, so that makes sense.

Answer (score 11):

Lacking another tazer, your only option to save the solider is to kill it.  Not sure what happened in your game, but killing the controller will not kill a mind controlled solider (unlike when enemies link).

Killing/stunning is the only option.  As per Shykin's comments, there is nothing in the psi tree to free a mind controlled soldier.

Comment: I can confirm this now. I finished a Psi tree and it does not include a way to get rid of the mind control. Kill or stun the enemy. If you make the enemy panic, it might drop the mind control in a panic but... good luck with that.

Comment: @Shykin what if you mind control the unit doing the mind controlling or being mind controlled?

Comment: I think the mind control is like a status affect which is why I doubted panic working. It's not that he is continuously channeling the mind control or using an ability. That person just now has a status that makes them an enemy.

Comment: What if you stun the soldier being mind controlled? Has anyone tried that?

Comment: @SaintWacko not yet, but it worked in the original!

Answer (score 4):

I used disabling shot with my sniper to buy some time to kill the controller

Comment: Could you give some more details?  Why is this an effective strategy?  What do you have to look out for when using this strategy?  Stuff like that would really help your answer.

Comment: This really doesn't answer my question. I was interested in recovering my soldier *without* killing the controller.

Comment: disabling shot is a good idea, makes the mind controlled soldier not be able to act on the next turn since he'll have to reload

Comment: disabling shot > battle scanner. Such a sweet ability and it can turn the tide for you in a battle. Cant tell you how many lives I've saved by disabling Sectopods. Add double tap and you have 2 potential kills (at the very least 2 less returning fire) on the next round.

Answer (score 1):

I tried arcing the guy under mind control (the first time it happens in the game) and you can't do it - no target.

The soldier doesn't die when the link is broken and you get more of the pink commander aliens in the next mission to capture so no great loss if you just kill the commander there.

You may be able to zapp the alien commanders instead but I didn't try it.

Answer (score -3):

Complete the mission.  mind control will go away.

Comment: This doesn't actually help in the slightest, as the only way to finish the mission is to kill everything, and I specifically say I do not want to kill the commander.